# change how XmlSerializer serializes empty elements

Tags: c#, xmlserializer

I am using the XmlSerializer. It serializes the object just fine but the client requires required empty elements to be in this format `<star:Confirm/>`.  The serializer instead serializes the empty elements to `<star:Confirm></star:Confirm>` is there a way to change it to serialize the way the client requires.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying different things I accidentally happened upon the solution.  I set the `XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable` to true like the previous answer suggested.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName = "Confirm", IsNullable=true)]
    public ConfirmType Confirm
    {
        get
        {
            return this.confirmField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.confirmField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("Confirm");
        }
    }
```

Then when setting the confirm type in the code I used the default constructor instead of setting Confirm to null.

```
retval.ConfirmBODDataArea.Confirm = new ConfirmType();
```

This serialized as `<star:Confirm/>`

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about default values and that I should be using the default constructor instead of = Nothing in vb.net code! :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try setting the [`XmlElementAttribute.IsNullable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.isnullable.aspx) property to `true`. However, bear in mind `xsi:nil="true"` attribute will be output as a consequence.