# XmlSerializer. Keep null string properties?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [XML Serialization and null value - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711723/xml-serialization-and-null-value-c-sharp)
>   [change how XmlSerializer serializes empty elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935582/change-how-xmlserializer-serializes-empty-elements)

How to make XmlSerializer store empty tags for string properties having null values, instead of skipping this property?

Comment: @Royi Namir, It's not the same. I don't need xsi:nil="true" values as well.

Answer (score 7):

You mean you want this:

```
<parent>
    <child1>Hello World</child1>
    <child2 />
</parent>
```

instead of

```
<parent>
    <child1>Hello World</child1>
</parent>
```

your class should look like this:
The serializer calls a `ShouldSerializePropertyName` method by definition (if exists) to determine if a property should be serialized (like Windows Forms Designer, too).

```
public class Parent
{
    [XmlElement("Child1")]
    public string Child1 { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Child2")]
    public string Child2 { get; set; }

    public bool ShouldSerializeChild2() { return true; }

}
```