# Handle null while Serializing Class to xml in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am trying to Serialize a class in C# this works fine when there is no null value in the object. Following is the class

```
public class EnquiryResponseInfo
{
    public string EnquiryId { get; set; }
    public EnquiryViewModel Enquiry { get; set; }
}
```

When I supply the following value it works great.

```
EnquiryResponseInfo tt = new EnquiryResponseInfo()
{
    EnquiryId = "xxx",
    Enquiry = new EnquiryViewModel()
    {
        Name = "Test user",
        Address = "Test Address"
    }
}
```

But when **Enquiry** is null it does not Serialize. I have a condition where the **Enquiry** will be null but there will be value in the **EnquiryId** there.

Following is the method to Serialize the class.

```
public static string Serialize<T>(T toSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
        return textWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: "But when Enquiry is null it does not Serialize." - Enquiry does not serialize? or the entire type does not serialize? it should work fine if the property is null - what exactly happens? example showing it working fine, with output: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/bd817bebd0f4a3d52c5edf0bb4f0fcf8

Comment: List<EnquiryResponseInfo> ApplicationInfo = new List<EnquiryResponseInfo>()
                                    {
                                        new EnquiryResponseInfo()
                                        {
                                            EnquiryId = "e30a092d-b7c1-4516-8e48-50efe307c7e5",
                                            Enquiry = null
                                        }
                                    };

Comment: There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EnquiryResponseInfo]'.

Gives me this error...

Comment: "There was an error reflecting type 'System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[EnquiryResponseInfo]'" - tip: look at `.InnerException` - and `.InnerException.InnerException` etc (as far down as it goes); `XmlSerializer` is actually *really good* at telling you what went wrong, but it is often a few levels down the exception stack

Comment: here's an updated gist that uses your `Serialize<T>` method, and uses a `List<EnquiryResponseInfo>` to match the post/comments: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/503a885c291a4eeee2be201473059f75 - it *works fine* - so: whatever the problem is, it *isn't in the question*; you need to either post enough code for us to repro the problem, or look at the nested exceptions

Comment: Dictionary<string, string[]> dd = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

this is not being serialized buddy...

Comment: literally nothing in the question uses `Dictionary<string, string[]>` - can you show this in full context?

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911514/why-doesnt-xmlserializer-support-dictionary

Answer (score 2):

Try to decorate the property **Enquiry** with 
    `[XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]`

Quoted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18515158/how-to-include-null-properties-during-xml-serialization/18515224#18515224)

Comment: I figure out that now, I think the usage of this value is to prevent the serializer from serializing the value if its null, is it right? @MarcGravell

Comment: no, not really; it already does that - this just causes it to be serialized *in a specific way* when null, i.e. expressed in xml as a nil

Answer (score 0):

The code as shown in the question and comments [is perfectly fine](https://gist.github.com/mgravell/503a885c291a4eeee2be201473059f75); `XmlSerializer` has reasonable default behaviors with `null`, so: that isn't the problem.

Whatever *is* happening : it isn't shown in the question. Most likely, there are other properties on `EnquiryViewModel` that are not friendly for `XmlSerializer` - perhaps they are non-public types, or have no public parameterless constructor. The way to find out is to look at the **nested exceptions** - for example, in `Serialize<T>`:

```cs
try
{
    // ... what you had before
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    while (ex != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
    throw;
}
```

This should tell you what *exactly* it finds objectionable about the model, in the debug output (or just put a break-point on the `Debug.WriteLine` line, and read all of the messages in the debugger).

Answer (score -1):

keep your property as nullable which would solve the problem. Example code u can refer below.

```
 [XmlRoot("test")]  
    public class Test {  
        int? propertyInt;  
        string propertyString;  

        [XmlAttribute("property-int")]  
        public int PropertyInt {  
            get { return (int)propertyInt; }  
            set { propertyInt = (int)value; }  
        }  

        public bool PropertyIntSpecified {  
            get { return propertyInt != null; }  
        }  

        [XmlAttribute("property-string")]  
        public string PropertyString {  
            get { return propertyString; }  
            set { propertyString = value; }  
        }  
    }  

    class Program {  
        static void Main(string[] args) {  

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));  
            serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new Test() { PropertyInt = 3 });  //only int will be serialized  
            serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new Test() { PropertyString = "abc" }); // only string will be serialized  
            serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, new Test() { PropertyInt = 3, PropertyString = "abc" }); // both - int and string will be serialized  


        }  
    }
```